# AutoEventWireUp = true and PAge_Load Handles added in Code behind. Page_Load function called only once

Tags: asp.net

I am not able to understand AutoEventWireup. 
I have the following code in Markup page

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb"    Inherits="TestWebApp._Default" %>
```

and in Code behind file as

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    sTest = sTest & " IN Page load "
End Sub
```

When referring about this property this page load will be called twice as explained in
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/what-is-the-autoeventwireup-attribute-in-Asp-Net/

but the page_load function called only once. CAN ANY ONE HELP ME?
WHY?

Comment: instead of `Handles` keyword, try using `AddHandler` in `OnInit` or `Page_Init` - for example, `AddHandler Me.Load, AddressOf Page_Load`

Answer (score 0):

The article you've linked says:

> This *can* result in the same event code being called twice

I think it's quite a bit misleading, because it doesn't mean it *must* result that way.

It will, if you have declared the event handler in the header:

`onload="Page_Load"`

or have added it explicitly:

`this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Page_Load);`

Because it will be called due to the manual subscription *and* to the `AutoEventWireup`.

So if you've only set `AutoEventWireup` to `true` and not subscribed to the event by yourself, it will only be called once.